# How to store age in SQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table as follows:

```
 $sql="CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(
 ID INT(3) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 Age INT(3) NOT NULL,
 Address VARCHAR(40)
)";
```

I am supposed to calculate and store the age from date of birth.I first found the last index by:

```
$last=mysqli_insert_id($sqli); //$sqli is DB connecting variable
```

Next I retrieved the DOB from DB by

```
  $sql="SELECT YEAR(Date) FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID='$last'";
  $sql2=$sqli->query($sql);
  if($sql2)
  {
   echo "date retrieved";
   $row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql2);
   $rdate=$row['YEAR(Date)'];
   }
```

I retrieved the current date too similarly as:

```
 $cdate;
 $sql="SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())";
 $sql2=$sqli->query($sql);
 if($sql2)
 {
 $row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql2);
 $cdate=$row['YEAR(CURDATE())'];
 }
```

Then I tried to find the difference in dates to get age by:

```
      $diff=abs(strtotime($cdate)-strtotime($rdate));
      $diff=floor($diff/(24*60*60*365));
      echo "$diff";

      $sql="INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(Age) VALUES('$diff') WHERE ID IS '$last'";
      if($sqli->query($sql)===TRUE)
      echo "age updated";
      else
      echo " Sorry age not updated: ".$sqli->error;
```

I execute but the query fails with error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ID IS 
'18'' at line 1
```

Comment: IS is not a valid keyword, use = to compare for equality.

Comment: INSERT doesn't use a WHERE clause. This mistake has been made often.

Comment: Don't save the age of the employee, save the date of birth instead. It makes your life much easier.

Comment: You would normally store date of birth

Comment: You probably want to use `update`. Insert would create a totally new employee, that only has age and no name or address -- and a different Id.

Comment: Do **not** store the age, just the date of birth. You can calculate the age in any query dynamically. Also, you would need an update statement to change an existing record, not an insert.

Comment: @AndyG `is` is a valid keyword in sql, see `is [not] null`

Comment: @Shadow yeah I know, but not in this context. I could have elaborated.

Comment: Yeah it worked.Thank you so much for the help.